# How do I style Monotouch Dialog Section?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, uitableview

I want to style Monotouch Dialog **Section** like this (change the blue background to an image of my own)...

[image]

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the HeaderView of your Section to a new UILabel object. UILabels are descendant of UIView, so they fit perfectly for this.

Make sure you set the background to black, the font to the one you want, and the frame size to (320,22). MonoTouch uses that frame size to figure how big the header should be.